# DB2 SQL how to make null value become 0?

Tags: mysql, db2

May I know how to make a null value show in an SQL result as 0?

```
String SQL = " SELECT A.CNCODE,C.TOTPREM,B.ORDER_AMOUNT,DECIMAL(D.AMOUNT,12,2) AS AMOUNT FROM TB_ORDER A,"+
             " TB_ORDER2 B, TB_ORDER3 C LEFT JOIN TB_ORDER4 D ON C.UKEY2=D.UKEY"+
             " WHERE C.UKEY2='0012254' AND C.UKEY2=B.UKEY2 AND C.UKEY2=A.UKEY "；                
      SQL += " WITH UR";
```

In the current SQL result, amount is shown as "`-`" indicating NULL; how to make it "0.00"?

```
===========================================
CNCODE | TOTPREM | ORDER_AMOUNT | AMOUNT
===========================================
I0012254 |136.54 |       5      |     -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql you can use `coalesce` function to convert `null` as `0` while selecting the data

```
mysql> select coalesce(null,0);
+------------------+
| coalesce(null,0) |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select coalesce(123,0);
+-----------------+
| coalesce(123,0) |
+-----------------+
|             123 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: COALESCE also works in DB2; it is part of Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query..

```
 select CNCODE, TOTPREM, ORDERAMOUNT, IFNULL(AMOUNT,0)(select A.CNCODE as CNCODE, C.TOTPREM as TOTPREM,  
 B.ORDER_AMOUNT as ORDERAMOUNT, DECIMAL(D.AMOUNT,12,2) AS AMOUNT FROM TB_ORDER A,
 TB_ORDER2 B, TB_ORDER3 C LEFT JOIN TB_ORDER4 D ON C.UKEY2=D.UKEY
 WHERE C.UKEY2='0012254' AND C.UKEY2=B.UKEY2 AND C.UKEY2=A.UKEY ) temp
```